# What happens with two Pledges of Loyalty attached to the same creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

This is a similar question, but a slightly different situation, so no duplicate: [What happens if I have two Pledges of Loyalty attached to a creature?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/19091/what-happens-if-i-have-two-pledges-of-loyalty-attached-to-a-creature)

Now to my scenario:

Let's say I have two [Grizzly Bears](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrizzly%20Bears%5d) with one [Pledge of Loyalty](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPledge%20of%20Loyalty%5d) attached to each of them. Now my opponent casts e.g. [Back to Nature](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBack%20to%20Nature%5d), killing both of my Pledges. I would like to keep my Bears protected, so I cast [Second Sunrise](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSecond%20Sunrise%5d) during the end step. Note that no other cards were put into any graveyard this turn, so it would revive only the two Pledges. While it is on the stack, my opponent decides to bounce one of my Grizzly Bears with a blue instant of your choice.

Now, the Sunrise resolves, I have to put my Pledges back and since the remaining Grizzlies are the only creature, both have to enchant it as per rule 303.4f. Now, I would think that they would enter the battlefield simultaneously, so no Pledge will be there "first" and prevent the other from attaching.

Is that correct so far?
What will happen afterwards? Will both Pledges be put into my graveyard again? Will one of them, or even both, survive?

Comment: I believe the controlling player chooses the stack order in such cases. Stuff doesn't just happen all at once, there is still a stack decided by the player. EDIT: Seems I am wrong according to the first answer.

Comment: @CyberClaw: Second Sunrise's effect doesn't put objects on the stack. Instead, it moves all objects from the graveyard to the battlefield as a single action. There is no specific rule illustrating this, as it depends on what the individual spell does. If it would, for example, create copies and cast them, that would use the stack - simply returning cards to the battlefield, however, doesn't. Players only get to arrange multiple objects on the stack that are put there at the same time.

Comment: Yeah like I said, seems I was wrong. I recalled somewhere that you'd order them into the stack at your choice on this mass effect cards, but I'm probably mixing it with some other card game, or it's probably some rule that has changed since I stopped obsessing with MTG.

Answer (score 8):

For completeness' sake:

> 303.4f. If an Aura is entering the battlefield under a player’s control by any means other than by resolving as an Aura spell, and the effect putting it onto the battlefield doesn’t specify the object or player the Aura will enchant, that player chooses what it will enchant as the Aura enters the battlefield. The player must choose a legal object or player according to the Aura’s enchant ability and any other applicable effects.

All cards returned by Second Sunrise are returned at the same time, so you can choose the Bears as the creature to attach them to for both Auras.
Right after it resolves, you will have a Grizzly Bears enchanted with both Pledges, two instances of Protection from White (and Green) that each don't remove the Aura that grants it.

Now, State-Based Actions are checked - simultaneously for each card, as per the following rule:

> 704.3. (...) the game checks for any of the listed conditions for state-based actions, then performs all applicable state-based actions simultaneously as a single event. (...)

Since both Auras are illegal at this time, they will both be put in your graveyard as a State-Based Action, even though a single one of them could remain on the creature (which SBAs don't check for).

> 704.5n. If an Aura is attached to an illegal object or player (...), that Aura is put into its owner’s graveyard.